# how to update only the selected fields from a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, sql-update

i made a query to do my work. but it does that work with some errors.

1)i have 6 image fields and some other fields in the mysql table

2)to update i use html form with 6 file upload filed and labeled as image1 image2...

3)so if i want to update only the 5th image i have to upload new image to image5 filed in form.

to update mysql table i made this query.

```
$image=array(
1 =>$_FILES['image1']['name'],
2 =>$_FILES['image2']['name'],
3 =>$_FILES['image3']['name'],
4 =>$_FILES['image4']['name'],
5 =>$_FILES['image5']['name'],
6 =>$_FILES['image6']['name'],
);
$i=1;
    $sql  = "UPDATE salehotel ";
    $sql .="SET"." ";
foreach($image as $value){
    if(!$value==""){    
    $sql .=  "`image".$i."`"."="."'". $value ."'".",". " ";
    $i++;
    }

}

$sql .="
      `name`='$name',
      `status`='$status',
      `type`='$type',
      `location`='$location',
      `price`='$price',
      `description`='$description'
    WHERE  
      `property_id`='$edit'
      ";
```

3)when i use this to update all 6 images there is no errors and it updates every thing.

4)but when i try to update single image, (ex: think if i want to update image5) either i select a file from image5 field, this query always update first image in the table.

5)i know why it happens. in my query inside the foreach loop i'm looking only for $values not equal to "". and then increment $i. so it incremented only one time. so it update image1 either i wanted to update image5.

6) so how can i get ride of this error ?

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: change the foreach() loop to a for() loop and count to 5 every time checking if if there is a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$_FILES['image2']['name']='zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz';

$image=array(
1 =>$_FILES['image1']['name'],
2 =>$_FILES['image2']['name'],
3 =>$_FILES['image3']['name'],
4 =>$_FILES['image4']['name'],
5 =>$_FILES['image5']['name'],
6 =>$_FILES['image6']['name'],
);


for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
if(!empty($image[$i])){    
    $sql .=  "`image".$i."`"."="."'". $image[$i] ."'".",". " ";
    }
}

echo $sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it by taking `$i++;` line, out of `if` block.

A modified version of your code, with the above mentioned fix and some other corrections :

```
<?php 

$image=array(
    1 =>$_FILES['image1']['name'],
    2 =>$_FILES['image2']['name'],
    3 =>$_FILES['image3']['name'],
    4 =>$_FILES['image4']['name'],
    5 =>$_FILES['image5']['name'],
    6 =>$_FILES['image6']['name'],
);
$i=1;

$sql  = 'UPDATE salehotel ';
$sql .= 'SET ';

foreach($image as $value)
{
    if(!$value=='')
        $sql .=  '`image'.$i.'` ='."'". $value ."'".', ';

    $i++;
}

$sql .="
      `name`='$name',
      `status`='$status',
      `type`='$type',
      `location`='$location',
      `price`='$price',
      `description`='$description'
    WHERE  
      `property_id`='$edit'
      ";
```

Try not to use double quotes, unless you have variables or other double quotes inside.

A better solution would be using foreach loop ability to have a `key`, like this:

```
<?php

$image=array(
    1 =>$_FILES['image1']['name'],
    2 =>$_FILES['image2']['name'],
    3 =>$_FILES['image3']['name'],
    4 =>$_FILES['image4']['name'],
    5 =>$_FILES['image5']['name'],
    6 =>$_FILES['image6']['name'],
);

$sql  = 'UPDATE salehotel ';
$sql .= 'SET ';

foreach($image as $key=>$value)
{
    if(!$value=='')
        $sql .=  '`image'.( $key + 1 ).'` ='."'". $value ."'".', ';
}
...
...
```